# Android download data on scroll - solve list changes between requests

Tags: android, scroll, infinite-scroll, endlessscroll

I need to implement an application similar to Facebook Messenger. I implemented an endless list which request more users if the list reaches the bottom when scrolling. The problem is the order of the list. It might change between requests. In Facebook Messenger the list of users is ordered with respect to time of conversation. Between app requests I may talk with somebody and the list order on server changes. So the following can occur:

Initial list on server

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Each request downloads 4 users.

First request:
1 2 3 4

Data order changed on server between requests from the app:

5 1 2 3 4 6 7 8

Second Request:

4 6 7 8

The list in android app:

1 2 3 4 4 6 7 8

How to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by `Change between requests`? what happened?

Comment: The change between requests means that some events change the order of elements from the server. The facebook messenger keeps the list of friends ordered respective to the most recent talk you had with them. So the list is changing between the app request.